# Relativistic corrections to quantum mechanics of Coloumb potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics

Systems of charged particles (such as atomic nuclei and electrons) can be described by nonrelativistic quantum mechanics with the Coloumb interaction potential. A fully relativistic description is given by quantum electrodynamics which is much more complex.

Is it possible to expand various quantities in QED as power series in 1/c i.e. around the nonrelativistic approximation? Examples of relevant quantities are:

- Ground state energy of a given set of charged particles
- Excited state energies
- Scattering cross sections of charged particles & their bound states (assuming we trace over the photons in the final state)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Look Breit equation, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breit_equation

Comment: Valdimir, as your comment is providing an answer, could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible. Look Breit equation, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breit_equation

Comment: Thx Vladimir, this is indeed relevant to my question. However this only provides the answer to second order in 1/c. What about higher orders?

Comment: @Squark: Higher orders give radiation effects and cannot be reduced to non-relativistic potential terms depending solely on the inter-particle distances and velocities. They will include inevitably the propagating field variables. Do you want to include the radiated field too?

Comment: @Squark: Normally for slow motions it is the dipole filed approximation which is dominant. You may be interested in the filed multipole expansions known from Classical Electrodynamics.

Comment: well I want a computable expansion of the full QED. I didn't say it has to be reducible to potential terms